# Mac Os "cannot be installed on this computer"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, snow-leopard, leopard

So I got a second hand macbook(A1342, mid-2010) and I need to install mac os on it so I can upgrade the firmware(it had cloud ready installed on it) so I downloaded a snow leopard dmg file(it said for dvd btw) and used etcher on my Linux machine to burn it to a usb after extracting the img. It booted fine into the installer but then it said Mac OS cannot be installed on this computer. Do you have an ideas?

I've just a little stumped right now.

And extra info

I only got a Linux and Windows computer rn

The Linux one has a disk drive but the Windows doesnt

And I don't have the original installation disc

Comment: I'm not quite certain whether a 2010 Mac can do this, but see what happens if you hold either Cmd/R or Cmd/opt/R at the boot chimes. You *may* get to recovery or internet recovery. Also, from any method you can reach Disk Utility, check the drive is formatted GUID/HFS & not MBR/anything.

Comment: You should be able to install El Capitan. Search this site to find a link to download El Capitan from Apple.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/25/how-to-start-up-your-mac-in-internet-recovery-mode/) this Mac can use Internet Recovery, but only if it's had a firmware update, which may be the one the asker is trying to apply! This model originally came with 10.6.3, so it's possible the 10.6 download you have is too old. Does the Mac boot at all?

Comment: The mac certainly boots, I have ubuntu installed on it currently. It's that "Linux one has a disk drive" :P

Comment: OK so update, I tried using transmac and I had the same error so I'm trying again with a high seirea dmg

Comment: You didn’t answer any of my questions yet, though I see you did post this exact issue again. Instead could you please edit this question and add the requested info.